# Different time scaling between timestamps and watermarks

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a stream with sensors data that start from now() and emit data each second but their timestamp increase by 15 min.
Let's say now is 19:00:00 so we have

```
('TH1', '2023-01-17 19:00', 15.559) at 19:00:00 
('TH1', '2023-01-17 19:15', 12.008) at 19:00:01 
('TH1', '2023-01-17 19:30', 15.706) at 19:00:02
```

etc.
Since I am aware that late data will arrive with BoundedOutOfOrderness of x simulation days aka 24*(60/15)*x seconds in real time, I am struggling implementing a WatermarkStrategy and TimestampAssigner, because of future timestamps. The goal is to sum aggregate the events of a whole sim day aka 96 seconds.

So far, I have tried triggering the aggregator with `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows` but I think it would be better with `EventTime`. Some combinations of `BoundedOutOfOrderness` and TumblingEvent window didn't seem to work.
I'm new to flink and I'm trying to work on 1.6. From what I understand there isn't much code out there for me to find since this Watermark thing is of this new version.

Below is the code I thought would work

```
 KafkaSource<SensorMessage> consumer = KafkaSource.<SensorMessage>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(parameterTool.get("bootstrap.servers"))
                .setTopics(String.format("sensors.%s", topic))
                .setGroupId(parameterTool.get("group.id"))
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SensorMessageDeserializationSchema()).build();

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<SensorMessage> soso = env.fromSource(consumer, 
                WatermarkStrategy.
                        <SensorMessage>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(3*96)) // 3 days
                        .withTimestampAssigner(((sensorMessage, l) -> sensorMessage.timestamp)), 
                topic);

        soso.keyBy(s -> s.name)
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(96)))// sum 1 day
                .sum("value")
                .map(s -> s.name + ", " + s.value)
                .sinkTo(KafkaSink.<String>builder()
                        .setBootstrapServers(
                                parameterTool
                                        .getProperties()
                                        .getProperty("bootstrap.servers"))
                        .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
                                .setTopic("flink.output")
                                .setValueSerializationSchema(new SimpleStringSchema())
                                .build())
                        .build());
```

Comment: Where does 96 second come from? If You receive events every second it should be much more

Comment: 1 event per sec equals to 15 mins in simulation. so 96 secs real time equals 1 day in sim.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are mixing things here.

`ProcessingTime` is time measured by system clock, so in Your case 1 simulation day will have 96 seconds.

`EventTime` on the other hand does not use system clock at all and all time flow is measured based on `timestamp` of the events You receive, this means that even though You receive whole day worth of simulation in 96 seconds, from point of view of event time, the whole day has passed, so when defining out of orderness and window sizes, You need to define them from point of view of event time e.g. You want a window size of 24h not 96 seconds.

Comment: so I have 
```DataStream<SensorMessage> inputStream = env.fromSource(source,
                WatermarkStrategy.<SensorMessage>forMonotonousTimestamps().
                        withTimestampAssigner(((sensorMessage, l) -> sensorMessage.timestamp))
                        , "myTopic");

        inputStream
                .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(24))).allowedLateness(Time.hours(48))``` 
I should expect daily summation to occur every 24 seconds, since OoOrderness = 0 and recalc after 2 days because of allowedLateness?

Comment: Time flow is measured by event time, so if You receive events with timestamps increasing by 15m, this means that if You receive messages in correct order windws will be closed after 96 seconds.
Regarding the recalculation, by default every late event will cause recalculation of the window.

Comment: So I have WStrategy with monotonousTimestamps() and timestamp assigned from my pojo.I understood the time flow you analyzed and it indeed seems very logical, still the window of 24hrs never triggers. I am stuck at this point 3 days now.